# Need help to solve a question of Mensuration

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres, solid-geometry

The radius of base and slant height of a conical
vessel is $3$ cm and $6$ cm respectively. Find the
volume of sufficient water in the vessel such that when a sphere of radius $1$ cm is placed into it, water just immersed it?

Comment: What is the orientation of the conical vessel?

Comment: Cut the whole thing in half with a vertical plane, the cone and water surface becomes a triangle, the sphere an inscribed circle. Use this to figure out the distance from the water level to the tip of the cone. Cut the cone at this distance and calculate its volume. Subtract the volume of the sphere and you are done.